# Long IP Address Negotiation via Ethernet Adapter

Tags: macbook-pro, network, thunderbolt, ethernet

Have an M1 Max MacBook Pro connected to ethernet via a "Apple" USB-C to Ethernet adapter; white one.

The IP Address Negotiation process takes about 60 seconds. No other computer (mostly PCs) on the network have this problem. Tried different cables, tried different ports, and tried bypassing the rack to no avail. I tried a different Mac with a built in ethernet port and everything is normal.

This is a handicap because it happens every time my computer wakes up from sleep.

I have tried the Anker 2.5Gbps USB-C to Ethernet adapter. I am now trying an Apple Thunderbolt 2 to Thunderbolt 3 adapter with a Thunderbolt 2 Ethernet adapter connected. I have also tried a Thunderbolt hub with an ethernet port.

I have also tried a manual IP address reservation which didn't help.

The problem persists no matter what I do. Anybody have any experience with this?

Comment: A suggestion to try out: Try disabling IPv6 on the USB Ethernet interface. Does that help?

Comment: Try: Disable DHCP on the Mac, give it manual IP address outside the DHCP range. Does that work better?

Comment: @Gilby tried that. Noted in post

Comment: In the post you said manual IP address reservation. I took that to mean reservation on the router (DHCP server) rather than manual setting on the Mac. Sorry if I misunderstood.  There is no DHCP negotiation with a manual IP address. So if that is slow to start your problem is not with DHCP.